# how to make magento webpage avaliable only for registered users?

Tags: magento

I want to make my site private only to registered users. If any one try to access my homepage. the login screen should come first. People should register or login to enter into my site.

How to do this? Any Suggestion from magento experts?

Answer (score 6):

If you do programming then simple logic would be checking if user is logged in or not else redirect them to the login page using event: controller_action_predispatch.
1> In your config.xml add the following xml code:

```
...
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule_controller_action_predispatch>
                    <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                    <method>checkForLogin</method>
                </yourmodule_controller_action_predispatch>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</frontend>
...
```

2> Create a Observer.php in your Module's Model/ directory.
Here is the basic code that you need to use in your Observer class:

```
<?php
class YourCompany_Yourmodule_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object{

    public function checkForLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() != 'customer_account_login') {
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'))->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are interested with more robust solution with much more features ready to use for your B2B store then here is an awesome Magento Extension called 'Store Restriction Pro':
http://www.magepsycho.com/store-restriction-pro.html

Good Luck

---

### **Update** (13-11-27), JSOV

In order to allow the forgot password, login access and default funcionality, you can add an array of the default pages you want to give permissions, and then validate and redirect.
ex:

```
...
$allow = array('customer_account_login','customer_account_forgotpassword','customer_account_resetpassword','customer_account_loginpost','customer_account_forgotpasswordpost','customer_account_resetpasswordpost');
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !in_array(strtolower($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName()),$allow) ) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply epascarello,
could u please direct me with the folder & file name,,, on which .php file u want me to makes this changes.

Comment: How can we restrict the user to see any of the page of site if he is not registered and log in to site.

Comment: Can I do this by overriding index action of CMC IndexController?

Comment: @Muk yes can if you want to restrict cms pages only. But using event-observer would be the best way to go.

Comment: @MagePsycho Could you please elaborate more your provided solution?I have not worked with observers. Thanks.